# Multiplying year based vector with a year & month based matrix in R

Tags: r, sorting, date, split, dplyr

I have two data frames

```
df1 

Year  Farm 1  Farm 2  Farm 3
2015    1000    2000    1500
2016    500     2000    1000

df 2

Year Month  Farm 1 Farm 2 Farm 3
2015  Jan    1        1      3
2015  Feb    1        2      1
2016  Jan    2        2      2
2016  Feb    2        1      2
```

I want to multiply the annual values in df1 across the respective farms in df2 based on the year so that the output is...

```
df 3 

Year    Month   Farm 1      Farm 2      Farm 3
2015    Jan     1000        2000        4500
2015    Feb     1000        4000        1500
2016    Jan     1000        4000        2000
2016    Feb     1000        2000        2000
```

I've got the years properly formatted, but have been struggling to find the solution with group_by in dplyr.  Should I be trying a different path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Base R** Assuming `df1` and `df2` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, merge the data frames giving data frame `m`.    Then create a new data frame `df3` by replacing all but the first two coiumns of `d2` with the product of those same columns of `df2` and the appropriate columns of `m`.  No packages are used.

```
m <- merge(df2, df1, by = 1)
df3 <- replace(df2, -(1:2), df2[-(1:2)] * m[-(1:ncol(df2))] )
```

giving:

```
> df3
  Year Month Farm1 Farm2 Farm3
1 2015   Jan  1000  2000  4500
2 2015   Feb  1000  4000  1500
3 2016   Jan  1000  4000  2000
4 2016   Feb  1000  2000  2000
```

**2) sqldf** If you only have a few farms so that it is feasible to write them each out then:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select 
         Year, 
         b.Month, 
         a.Farm1 * b.Farm1 Farm1,
         a.Farm2 * b.Farm2 Farm2,
         a.Farm3 * b.Farm3 Farm3
       from df2 b left join df1 a using (Year)")
```

giving:

```
  Year Month Farm1 Farm2 Farm3
1 2015   Jan  1000  2000  4500
2 2015   Feb  1000  4000  1500
3 2016   Jan  1000  4000  2000
4 2016   Feb  1000  2000  2000
```

### Note

```
Lines1 <- "
Year  Farm1  Farm2  Farm3
2015    1000    2000    1500
2016    500     2000    1000"

Lines2 <- "
Year Month  Farm1 Farm2 Farm3
2015  Jan    1        1      3
2015  Feb    1        2      1
2016  Jan    2        2      2
2016  Feb    2        1      2"

df1 <- read.table(text = Lines1, header = TRUE)
df2 <- read.table(text = Lines2, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with join from `data.table`.  Join the second dataset ('df2') with the first ('df1') `on` the 'Year' column, and multiply the `.SD` (Subset of data.table based on the columns specified in the `.SDcols`) with the corresponding columns in the first data, assign (`:=`) the output to update the 'Farm" columns in the second dataset

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- grep("Farm", names(df1), value = TRUE)
setDT(df2)[df1, (nm1) := .SD * mget(paste0("i.", names(.SD))), 
           on = .(Year), .SDcols = nm1]
df2
#   Year Month Farm1 Farm2 Farm3
#1: 2015   Jan  1000  2000  4500
#2: 2015   Feb  1000  4000  1500
#3: 2016   Jan  1000  4000  2000
#4: 2016   Feb  1000  2000  2000
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem by transforming the data frames into long format, joining them, and then doing the calculation. Here is an example:

```
# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Make-up data
df1 = data.frame(Year = 2008:2018,
                 Farm1 = runif(n = 11, min = 0, max = 2000),
                 Farm2 = runif(n = 11, min = 0, max = 2000),
                 Farm3 = runif(n = 11, min = 0, max = 2000))

df2 = expand.grid(Year = 2008:2018,
                  Month = month.abb[1:12]) %>% 
  mutate(Farm1 = runif(n = 132, min = 0, max = 10),
         Farm2 = runif(n = 132, min = 0, max = 10),
         Farm3 = runif(n = 132, min = 0, max = 10))

# Transform data into long format
df1.long = df1 %>%
  gather(key = Farm, value = AnnualValue, Farm1:Farm3)

df2.long = df2 %>%
  gather(key = Farm, value = Value, Farm1:Farm3)

# Now left_join on Year and multiply columns
df.comb = left_join(df1.long, df2.long) %>% 
  mutate(NewValue = Value * AnnualValue)

# Transform back to wide format (if necessary)
df.comb.wide = df.comb %>% 
  select(-AnnualValue, -Value) %>% # drop values not included in wide format
  spread(key = Farm, value = NewValue)
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!